# Function that operates on Spark column as argument

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

**Edit: Finally figured it out myself. I kept using `select()` on `column` within the function, that's why it didn't work. I added my solution as comments withint the original question just in case it might be of use for somebody else.**

I'm working on an online course where I'm supposed to write the following function:

```
# TODO: Replace <FILL IN> with appropriate code

# Note that you shouldn't use any RDD operations or need to create custom user defined functions (udfs) to accomplish this task

from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, trim, col, lower

def removePunctuation(column):
    """Removes punctuation, changes to lower case, and strips leading and trailing spaces.

    Note:
        Only spaces, letters, and numbers should be retained.  Other characters should should be
        eliminated (e.g. it's becomes its).  Leading and trailing spaces should be removed after
        punctuation is removed.

    Args:
        column (Column): A Column containing a sentence.

    Returns:
        Column: A Column named 'sentence' with clean-up operations applied.
    """

    # EDIT: MY SOLUTION
    # column = lower(column)
    # column = regexp_replace(column, r'([^a-z\d\s])+', r'')
    # return trim(column).alias('sentence')

    return <FILL IN>

sentenceDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('Hi, you!',),
                                         (' No under_score!',),
                                         (' *      Remove punctuation then spaces  * ',)], ['sentence'])
sentenceDF.show(truncate=False)
(sentenceDF
 .select(removePunctuation(col('sentence')))
 .show(truncate=False))
```

I've written the code that gives me the required output for operations on the `DataFrame` itself:

```
# Lower case
lower = sentenceDF.select(lower(col('sentence')).alias('lower'))
lower.show()

# Remove Punctuation
cleaned = lower.select(regexp_replace(col('lower'), r'([^a-z\d\s])+', r'').alias('cleaned'))
cleaned.show()

# Trim
sentenceDF = cleaned.select(trim(col('cleaned')).alias('sentence'))
sentenceDF.show(truncate=False)
```

I just don't know, how to implement this code in my function, since it doesn't operate on the `DataFrame`, but only on the given `column`. I've tried different approaches, one was to create a new `DataFrame` out of the `column` input using

```
[...]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(column, ['sentence'])
[...]
```

within the function, but it doesn't work: `TypeError: Column is not iterable`. Other approaches were trying to directly operate on `column` within the function, always leading to `TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable`.

I've started with `(Py)Spark` a few days ago and still have conceptual problems regarding how to deal with rows and columns only. I would really appreciate any kind of help on the current issue.

Comment: This is assignment from edx cs105. you can check discussion in piazza.

Comment: and the regex should be r'([^a-zA-Z\d\s])+'

Comment: @offwhitelotus Actually no, since I use `lower()` on the column right before applying the RegEx so there is no need for `A-Z`.

Comment: @turingcomplete ah, yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a single line.

```
return re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9\s]','',text.lower().strip()).strip()
```